# flask sqlalchemy mysql encoding problems

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a simple database in mysql and i try to print results but encoding is wrong.
It happens with orm models and pure sql modes.

With same sqlalchemy conf, pure use works and flask app dont.
I also have tried with simple test in php and it works ok.

What am i doing wrong?

**Mysql variables**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'; 
    +--------------------------+----------------------------+
    | Variable_name            | Value                      |
    +--------------------------+----------------------------+
    | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
    | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
    | character_set_database   | utf8                       |
    | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
    | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
    | character_set_server     | utf8                       |
    | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
    | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
    +--------------------------+----------------------------+

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'; 
    +----------------------+-----------------+
    | Variable_name        | Value           |
    +----------------------+-----------------+
    | collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
    | collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
    | collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
    +----------------------+-----------------+
```

**Mysql table**

```
CREATE TABLE `dct_person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
   .
   .
   .
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**File test2.py -> ENCODING WORKING**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@localhost/db')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select name from dct_person limit 5")
for row in result:
    print "name:", row['name']
connection.close()
```

output

```
name: María de los Ángeles Félix Santamaría Espinosa
name: Bertahasa Bertahasa Honzca
name: Teresita Jiménez
```

**real flask application -> ENCODING FAIL**

in config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/db'
```

Command with flask-script

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Test db command file"""
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Command
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class TestDb(Command):
    "test db"

    def run(self):
        print "recode db"
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config.from_object('config')
        db = SQLAlchemy(app)

        result = db.engine.execute('SELECT id,name FROM dct_person  LIMIT 5')
        for r in result:
            print r.name
```

output

```
MarÃ­a de los Ãngeles FÃ©lix SantamarÃ­a Espinosa
Bertahasa Bertahasa Honzca
Teresita JimÃ©nez
```

Thanks

### EDIT: more info and tests

same conf in one file, thre ways of querying db and diferent results

test.py

```
print "\nFlask version (FAIL)"
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
result = db.engine.execute('SELECT id,name FROM dct_person  LIMIT 5')
for r in result:
    print r.name


print "\nPure version with connect (OK)"
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select id,name from dct_person limit 5")
for row in result:
    print row['name']
connection.close()


print "\nPure version without connect (FAIL)"
engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
result = db.engine.execute("select id,name from dct_person limit 5")
for row in result:
    print row['name']
```

python test.py

```
Flask version
Jaume Mateu i Bullich
Margarita Llobera Llompart
MarÃ­a de los Ãngeles FÃ©lix SantamarÃ­a Espinosa
Bertahasa Bertahasa Honzca
Teresita JimÃ©nez

Pure version with connect
Jaume Mateu i Bullich
Margarita Llobera Llompart
María de los Ángeles Félix Santamaría Espinosa
Bertahasa Bertahasa Honzca
Teresita Jiménez

Pure version without connect
Jaume Mateu i Bullich
Margarita Llobera Llompart
MarÃ­a de los Ãngeles FÃ©lix SantamarÃ­a Espinosa
Bertahasa Bertahasa Honzca
Teresita JimÃ©nez
```

### EDIT 2: other posible causes

if I print types in each case, the only case that works is ... wtf?
is my database data wrong encoded?

```
Flask version (FAIL)
MarÃ­a de los Ãngeles FÃ©lix SantamarÃ­a Espinosa
<type 'unicode'>

Pure version with connect (OK)
María de los Ángeles Félix Santamaría Espinosa
<type 'str'>

Pure version without connect (FAIL)
MarÃ­a de los Ãngeles FÃ©lix SantamarÃ­a Espinosa
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: i followed https://www.blueboxcloud.com/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell for solve this issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [try to set the charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819192/sqlalchemy-result-for-utf-8-column-is-of-type-str-why) in the database url.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/db?charset=utf8'
```

See the [SQLAlchemy documentation on MySQL, unicode section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#unicode).

Comment: @trilopin You could also use `print row['name'].decode("utf-8")` but this will not solve the basic encoding problem... I'm pretty sure that give charset in the connection string should fix the problem. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155264/how-do-i-get-sqlalchemy-to-correctly-insert-a-unicode-ellipsis-into-a-mysql-tabl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819192/sqlalchemy-result-for-utf-8-column-is-of-type-str-why)...

Comment: @trilopin Maybe look into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015098/why-does-sqlalchemy-create-engine-with-charset-utf8-return-python-type-str-and) issue and check your MySql version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I fixed it by setting the Flask configuration property `MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET`.

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'
```

The solution for this found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659945

Comment: At a glance, it looks like this is for Flask-MySQL not flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you guys talking about but I had a problem with `flask_mysqldb` and `utf8mb4` not showing `emojjs` after almost giving up on it

I look at flask_mysqldb source code and it was using

```
app.config['MYSQL_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'
```

not

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'
```

so I changed the app config from `MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET` to `MYSQL_CHARSET` and it works perfectly now