# Incorrect String error when adding emoji to a database through a form

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, forms, stored-procedures

I can successfully add emoji (i.e. utf8mb4 data) to tables using mysql using the terminal.

When my Python Flask website tries to send emoji to the same database table and field, the database returns the following incorrect string error:

(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8E' for column 'p_description' at row 1")

**UPDATE**

- I read the suggested threads and am not seeing how to block the server from overriding my local character-set-server setting.
- Added SET NAMES utf8mb4; before INSERT INTO, but no effect
- I checked as suggested in the comments (thanks!) and yes, all my database character settings are showing utf8mb4 where it is possible. This is what I get from mysql:

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character_set_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

=>

| Variable_name            | Value              |

| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |

| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |

| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |

| character_set_filesystem | binary             |

| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |

| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |

| character_set_system     | utf8               |

| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I am using an html form, jQuery, AJAX and Python Flask to send the data to the database. Python calls the SQL stored procedure below.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_addWish`(
    IN p_title varchar(45),
    IN p_description varchar(1000),
    IN p_user_id bigint
)
BEGIN
    SET NAMES utf8mb4; insert into tbl_wish(
        wish_title,
        wish_description,
        wish_user_id,
        wish_date
    )
    values
    (
        p_title,
        p_description,
        p_user_id,
        NOW()
    );
END
```

**Q: How do I force my website to send data to my database in the utf8mb4 format?

Comment: Check that your server character set is the same as your database and system character sets. Run `show variables like 'character_set%';` to see.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc) directly addresses your problem, though it may not have an exact solution for you.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax thanks! see update, all are showing utf8mb4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python Flask defaults to communicating with MySQL in MySQL's utf-8, i.e. it can't handle the full utf8mb4 range (which includes emojis). Flask will override the database charset settings, including the character-set-server setting in my.cf. Adding the following setting to the Flask app fixes the problem by forcing it to communicate with MySQL in utf8mb4:

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'

Answer (score 1):

I encountered almost the same problem recently, where accented characters were causing PHP `json_encode()` to complain about "malformed UTF8 characters." 
Much to-ing and fro-ing in the documentation eventually led me to a paragraph at the bottom of the page [10.5 Character Set Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-configuration.html) which states:

> … when `character_set_system` differs from `character_set_server` or
>   `character_set_client`, and you input characters manually (as database
>   object identifiers, column values, or both), these may be displayed
>   incorrectly in output from the client or the output itself may be
>   formatted incorrectly.

In fact, `character_set_system` defaults to **`utf8`** while `character_set_server` defaults to **`latin1`** — I dare not speculate why.

My solution was to explicitly set `character_set_server = utf8` (it defaults to `latin1`) and `collation_server = utf8_general_ci` (it defaults to `latin1_swedish_ci`) in the `[mysqld]` section of my `my.cnf` configuration file and then restart the service. The fact that these settings differed from the corresponding `*_system` settings apparently was the cause of my problem.

Some experimentation has confirmed that `character_set_system` ***must be*** **`utf8`** or the server won't start. The documentation says that `character_set_database` *can* be set differently from `character_set_server`, but I'm not currently equipped to test the effects of this.

Comment: Darwin, adding character-set-system = utf8mb4 to my.cnf prevented mysql server from starting. The server would not start again until I removed the line.

Comment: I'm going to spend Saturday experimenting. Meanwhile, if it was working with `*_system=utf8, *_server=utf8mb4`, then go with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store unicode character into the database you need to Define column character set to `utf8mb4`.

Also change character set of table if it is required.

it will help you store data in unicode formate

Thanks

Comment: As stated in the question, these are already defined as utf8mb4